# Does vscode-java come with code analysis?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I want unused variables to be greyed out. Does vscode-java support code analysis? I did not find anything in the settings.

I know that I could use the checkstyle extension.

Comment: This seems like a clear example of "visit their page, find the docs, and read up on what it supports"?

Comment: read the docs , go with the extension

Comment: Very clever, did you really think that I did not do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unused variables are now greyed out. Don't know what changed, but question is answered: Extension supports code analysis, if set up correctly.